# Using Spring Cache to cache a large value and using it to output a smaller one?

Tags: java, spring, caching

Our program is using Spring Cache to store a value reached when it the method is called for 30 days. Is there a way to make it use that same cache if that method receives a 7 day parameter for example?

For example, let's say I have a method that calls for every number from one to x. I call that method with x = 50, this result is cached. Is there a way for me to have the cache operate such that if that method is called again with x = 25 it simply uses the x = 50 cache to find the result?

Comment: Please re-read your question and clarify - it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Does the edit make it clearer?

Comment: much more so! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether this is generally possible really depends upon whether you can define a function that maps from input -> desired key. By default Spring Cache will use the method parameters to the `@Cacheable` annotated method as the caching key.

`KeyGenerator`'s default behaviour:

> Since caches are essentially key-value stores, each invocation of a
>   cached method needs to be translated into a suitable key for cache
>   access. Out of the box, the caching abstraction uses a simple
>   KeyGenerator based on the following algorithm:
>
> If no params are given, return SimpleKey.EMPTY. If only one param is
>   given, return that instance. If more the one param is given, return a
>   SimpleKey containing all parameters. This approach works well for most
>   use-cases; As long as parameters have natural keys and implement valid
>   hashCode() and equals() methods. If that is not the case then the
>   strategy needs to be changed.

There are a couple of options you could use to define your own custom key, you could implement `KeyGenerator` yourself, or you could use `spel` to define a function that maps the parameter to the key you'd like it to use. Check out http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key for some examples.